# Pass parameters with UnityAction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to send an UnityAction as a parameter for one of my methods, like so:

```
public void PopulateConversationList(string [] fullConversation, string onLastPagePrompt, string npcName, int stage, UnityAction action)
{
    conversations.Add(new Conversation(fullConversation, onLastPagePrompt, npcName, stage, action));
}

dialogHolder.PopulateConversationList(stage1, "Okay", _name, 1, QuestManager.Instance().ActivateQuest);
```

this works fine, but now I want to pass the following Action as a parameter:

```
public void ActivateQuest(int questId)
{
    Debug.Log("This is the id: " + questId);
}
```

However, it will not work when I use an action that has a parameter:

```
dialogHolder.PopulateConversationList(stage1, "Okay", _name, 1, QuestManager.Instance().ActivateQuest(2));
```

The above gives error: `Cannot convert from void to UnityAction`. 
How can I pass a UnityAction with a parameter, as a parameter?

I call the `Action` in the conversation like this:

```
dialog.OnAccept(ConvList[i].onLastPagePrompt, () =>
{
    ConvList[i].action();
    dialog.Hide();
});
```

EDIT: The solution I ended up going with:

```
enter dialogHolder.PopulateConversationList(stage1, "Okay", _name, 1, () =>
    {
        QuestManager.Instance().ActivateQuest(0);
    });
```

This way I can call several methods as well.

Comment: You didn't even bother to show `testMethod` function and also how `MyAction` is declared. These are required in order to help you.

Comment: @Programmer Sorry I was trying to make it more readable, guess I just made it worse. I edited the Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
public void PopulateConversationList(string[] fullConversation, string onLastPagePrompt, string npcName, int stage, UnityAction action)
```

The `action` argument does not accept any parameter but you are passing it a function that requires a parameter:

```
public void ActivateQuest(int questId)
{
    Debug.Log("This is the id: " + questId);
}
```

with:

```
dialogHolder.PopulateConversationList(stage1, "Okay", _name, 1, QuestManager.Instance().ActivateQuest(2));
```

Notice the `2` passed to the `ActivateQuest` function.

---

Passing parameter to `UnityEvent` is not really that simple as one would expect. You must derive from `UnityEvent` and also provide the type of parameter. In this case you want to pass int. You must create a class that derives from UnityEvent with `int` as generic.

`public class IntUnityEvent : UnityEvent<int>{}`

The `IntUnityEvent action` variable can then be passed around as parameter in your functions instead of `UnityAction action`.

Below is a simplified and generic solution provided so that it will be helpful to others too. Just add your other parameters to the `PopulateConversationList` function and you should be good to go. It's well commented.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class IntUnityEvent : UnityEvent<int>
{
    public int intParam;
}

public IntUnityEvent uIntEvent;

void Start()
{
    //Create the parameter to pass to the function
    if (uIntEvent == null)
        uIntEvent = new IntUnityEvent();

    //Add the function to call
    uIntEvent.AddListener(ActivateQuest);

    //Set the parameter value to use
    uIntEvent.intParam = 2;

    //Pass the IntUnityEvent/UnityAction to a function
    PopulateConversationList(uIntEvent);
}

public void PopulateConversationList(IntUnityEvent action)
{
    //Test/Call the function 
    action.Invoke(action.intParam);
}

//The function to call
public void ActivateQuest(int questId)
{
    Debug.Log("This is the id: " + questId);
}
```

**Note**:

If possible, avoid using `UnityEvent` in Unity. Use use C# `Action` and `delegate` since they are more easier to use. Also, they are much more faster than Unity's `UnityEvent`.

Comment: Thanks, Accepted cus it answers my question :) I ended up finding my own way, which also allows me to call several methods, which I need.

Answer (score 2):

So, everyone here fails to address the less than, greater than operator on the UnityAction.

It seems like you're well versed with the void UnityAction

```
public void CallAction(UnityAction action){
    action?.invoke();
}
```

But, say you want to pass a float.

```
public void SendFloat(UnityAction<float> action){
    action?.invoke(5.0f);
}
```

Or, if you want to pass a float and another action

```
public void SendFloatAndAction(UnityAction<float, UnityAction> action){
    action?.invoke(5.0f, ()=>
    {
        Debug.Log("Called");
    });
}
```

Pretty much, you can put whatever information that you want into the less than, greater than operator of the UnityAction to allow that to be passed as a parameter.

As stated in the Unity documentation, a UnityAction or Delegate that does not have an action assigned to it is null and attempting to invoke it will throw an error. Instead of adding an extra 2-3 lines for a null check, you can add a question mark (?) which will only invoke the UnityAction or Delegate if it is not null.

Unfortunately, the docs are inadequate to please my tastes after looking at the nicer React docs but here is the Unity Learn tutorial on delegates: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/delegates
And here are the docs for UnityAction although they do not do the type justice.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityAction.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityAction_4.html

If you want to use UnityAction, you must use UnityEngine.Events by adding the line `using UnityEngine.Events;` to the top of your script.

One last note, I have not experimented much with UnityAction calls but I believe that you are only allowed to set between 0 and 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this

```
    public void RegisterEvent<T, U, V>(object eventName, Action<T, U, V> handler)
{
    Register(eventName, handler);
}
```

Comment: It could be better if you provide explanation how your solution works.

Comment: This is a question about Unity c#, not general c#. There is a subtle but huge difference there. In Unity, you should not use Action, you should use UnityAction. Also, without the Register method, this answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        UnityAction unityAction = null;
        unityAction += () => Jamen1("UnityAction Jamen1");
        unityAction += Jamen2;
        unityAction += () =>
        {
            print("UnityAction Jamen3");
        };
        Jamen3(unityAction)
    }

    void Jamen1(string text)
    {
        print(text);
    }

    void Jamen2()
    {
        print("UnityAction Jamen2");
    }

    void Jamen3(UnityAction unityAction)
    {
        unityAction?.Invoke();
    }
```

Note: the ? is a null check.

```
// Null Check    
unityAction?.Invoke();

// Don't Null Check
unityAction.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use lambda expression to solve this problem

```
dialogHolder.PopulateConversationList(stage1, "Okay", _name, 1, () => {
    QuestManager.Instance().ActivateQuest(2);
});
```